# How to delete a file and not display location

Tags: c#, winforms

Delete a file in the Windows Temp directory using a simple form with a button, whether the file is there or not, if the button is pressed it will say completed.

As for the user not knowing the location: The file in the end will be obfuscated, but I don't need the form to throw an error if the file isn't found and display the error saying File not found at location.....

I've tried using the code, it seems to open a console. I tried to add the test123.txt file but the file didn't delete.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strCmdText;
    strCmdText = "del /q/f/s %TEMP%/test123.txt ";
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
}
```

I would like to able to delete a text file without the user knowing the location of the file even if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Combine `File.Delete` and `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables`.

Comment: Why don't you just use `File.Delete()`?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.delete  The user only knows the information you show them.  (Though keep in mind that if the user is physically operating their own workstation then they *do* have access to diagnostic information outside of your program.  There's nothing stopping them from monitoring their file system and observing what your program does there.)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string tmpDir = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%TEMP%");
    string pathToFile = Path.Combine(tmpDir, "test123.txt");
    if (File.Exists(pathToFile))
    {
        File.Delete(pathToFile);
    }
    //Print completed where you want
}
```

Note that it really would be better to carry out name of temp file to a variable outside method and use it. It helps you in that case if you would like to generate temp files without hardcoded names using timestamps, uuid etc in name

**UPDATE** Bellow my answer [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) advised to use special method in Path class from System.IO to get path to %TEMP% folder. And after reading documentation on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettemppath?view=netframework-4.8) I agree that this will be a better way to get path to %TEMP% folder.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string tmpDir = Path.GetTempPath();
    string pathToFile = Path.Combine(tmpDir, "test123.txt");
    if (File.Exists(pathToFile))
    {
        File.Delete(pathToFile);
    }
    //Print completed where you want
}
```

Comment: And ALWAYS remember to handle exceptions in code that handles files. Number one source of errors in my experience.  The File.Delete may throw an exception.

Comment: Thank you, what is the best way to display a message saying completed? I do like how it doesn't return an error if the file isn't there.

Comment: @BeLostTwice it will return error if you don't have permissions to delete file or file is locked (using) by other process. About message try something `MessageBox.Show("Completed");`

Comment: If the user doesn't have permission, it wont show the location of the file will it?

Comment: It will throw `UnauthorizedAccessException` in your code and in this exception there will be path to file in message. Message box won't show anything except "Completed". For avoid this you can use `try { File.Delete(pathToFile); MessageBox.Show("Completed");} catch(UnauthorizedAccessException) { MessageBox.Show("File not deleted, access to temporary file denied"); }`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to delete a file is like @Lemm suggested. But if you really want to use cmd, you can try the code below:

```
ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/k del /q/f/s %TEMP%/test123.txt");
ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
```

Comment: No don't want to use CMD and no don't want to delete a folder. Delete a file in the Windows Temp directory using a simple form with a button